# Heroku: Pull to a project branch

Tags: git, heroku

I messed up and merged a branch to the master, which is live in Heroku.

Is there a way to pull the code from Heroku directly to a branch of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I messed up and merged a branch to the master

Follow those steps to "recover" your messed up master

```
# checkout dummy branch - so you will be able to delete your local master
git checkout -b dummy1

# delete the "bad" branch (locally)
git branch -D master

# get updates from the server (in case there are changes)
fir fetch --all --prune  

#checkout the original master
git checkout master

# remove the dummy branch 
git branch -D dummy1
```

And you are all set to go. your master is now the same as the branch onthe remote server.